# Is it possible to use docker image for installing OS

Tags: docker, operating-system

Is it possible to use docker image for installing OS on local machine?

I want to use docker image for installing OS with all docker image settings.

I have docker image with tensorflow GPU installation within, and container running with this image doesn't work properly. I assume this problem with RAM volume allocated for docker VM Engine.

Comment: A Docker image doesn't contain a kernel and doesn't directly interact with hardware devices.  Usually these would stack the other way – given an OS (image) you'd run Docker on top of that.